# Ruby On Rails - Order By external column count

Tags: ruby

I have table rooms and table contributor.

On Ruby on Rails :

**How order rooms depending on the number of contributors (conributor.room_id == room.id)?**

Comment: can you provide more information (associations, schema)? and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Room` model `has_many :contributors`, you can do this:

```
Room.joins(:contributors).group('rooms.id').order('COUNT(contributors.id) DESC')
```

That will return an array of rooms, with the one's with most contributors first.

However, note that rooms that have no contributors will not appear in the list as they have no join to contributors.